# Declare default parameter circular reference without pointers?

Tags: c++, header, definition, circular-reference

Is there any way to declare these classes in a header file without indirection?

```
// Forwards declaration of B
class B;

class A
{
public:
    // Default parameter referring to B.  May return its parameter
    const B& func(const B& b = B());
};

class B
{
public:
    // B ctors
    B() {}
    B(const B&) {}

    // B has A as a member
    A a;
};
```

Visual C++ 2008 tells me with this:

```
error C2514: 'B' : class has no constructors
```

and points to the forward declaration of B ("class B;") and obviously can't see B's constructors below.  A can't follow B because B contains A as a member.

If indirection must be used, what's the best way?  Perhaps in C++0x B's A could be a unique_ptr member?  Or maybe there's a boost class purely to sidestep this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of a default parameter declare two overloads, one that takes a `B` by reference and one that takes no parameter.  In the one that takes no parameter, call the other with `B()`, which will work because that method can be defined after `B` is defined.

```
...
    void func();
    void func(const B& b);
};

class B...

void A::func() { func(B()); }
void A::func(const B&) { }
```

Update:

> func() returns a const B&...

That's probably not a good idea.  With that definition, something like:

```
const B& foo = a.func();
foo.bar();
```

would cause the dreaded "undefined behavior" (i.e., crash) because the `B` to which you have a reference will be destroyed as soon as the first statement is complete.  Returning things other than class members by reference is usually a bad idea.

If you really want to do this, then I think you're stuck with forcing the caller to explicitly pass in `B()`, that is have no default parameter.

```
a.func(B()).bar();
```

(This is the only way to avoid undefined behavior with such a function.)

Of course you could just return a copy instead of a reference, but I presume you have a reason for not doing that.

Depending on what you're doing you may be able to set up better semantics using a smart pointer like `shared_ptr` instead of references so that you can effectively ignore the lifetimes of the objects.  You then have to start being careful of reference cycles instead, however.

I can't tell what you're trying to use this for, but you might want to have a look at some [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29) to see if there is an established best-practice for it.  You may find that this little problem is a symptom of an unfortunate choice of class structure or containment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  That would work, but I forgot to mention - func() returns a const B&, and may return its parameter, so a version with no parameter makes no sense.  What then?